# Binding Dictionary<string, DataTable> to ItemsControl not working

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding, itemscontrol

I need to display each datatable(value) in the dictionary when the dictionary item in the list is expanded. And the dictionary item's key should be the expander header. The view model populates the data correctly, but nothing gets displayed on the UI. How do I get the list of datatables to display on the UI 
So far this is what I have:

```
<!-- Data grid template -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="ValuesTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="data grid header text" Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Value[0]}"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- List of data tables -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myDictionary}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Expander IsExpanded="True" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <Expander.Header>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="0,0,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Expander.Header>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ValuesTemplate}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
      </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, the [`ItemsControl.ItemsSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) can be bound to any type that implements `IEnumerable`. So, how is `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` represented in terms of `IEnumerable`? It does so as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

So, you could ignore the fact that you have a dictionary, and instead think of this as an enumeration of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` objects.

---

Now, you have the primary portion implemented *mostly* correct. You have an `ItemsControl`, properly bound, and you are applying a `DataTemplate` to each item. But, remember that each item is a `KeyValuePair`. So, the `TextBlock.Text` property is being bound correctly to the **Key** property, but the Content is being bound to the item (`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue`) itself. This might be on purpose, but my guess is that you'd probably want the ContentControl to be bound to the **Value** property instead.

The second part is that you want to apply a `ContentTemplate` to each `Content` within your original `DataTemplate`. I see at least one, perhaps two potential mistakes:

1. You're `ValuesTemplate` seems to be working under the assumption that the content is a type of `DataTable`, when it is actually a type of `KeyValuePair<string, DataTable>`. In this case I would bind the `Content` to the **Value** property.
2. You're `ValuesTempalte` also seems to be binding the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `Values[0]`. My assumption here is that, again, you thought your content is a type of `DataTable` when it isn't, and even if that were the case, why bind the `ItemsSource` to the first row in the `DataTable`? Is your `DataTable` composed of rows, each of which are a sequence themselves? I'm guessing you simply want to do `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />`.

---

TL;DR;

```
<!-- Data grid template -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="ValuesTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="data grid header text" Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" />
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- List of data tables -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Expander IsExpanded="True" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <Expander.Header>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="0,0,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Expander.Header>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ValuesTemplate}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
      </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you.
My intention was to bind the Value property to the data grid's item source.
But it seems like I have got it wrong. I tried your suggestion but neither the textblock nor the grid show up. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Just making sure, if you used @m-y `s code ,you corrected the Binding he made, right? he used ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}", and you have ItemsSource="{Binding myDictionary}"

Comment: They are both the same right? myDictionary is a list of key value pairs -
List<KeyValuePair<string, DataTable>> myDictionary.

Comment: I changed the list of KeyValue pairs to an observable collection of Key value pairs and the key shows up as the text in the textblock. But the data table is still not being displayed.

Comment: @anya: You can leave it as a `Dictionary<string, DataTable>`, the ItemsSource will read it as a sequence of `KeyValuePair<string, DataTable>` automatically for you.

Comment: @m-y: Do you mean the ItemsSource for the ItemsControl?

Comment: I had condition binding on the datagrid, which if not satisfied would hide the datagrid. The binding was referring to a Property that no longer existed which caused the datagrid to be hidden. (I cannot believe I didn't see that!).
Thank you so much =). It works perfectly!

Comment: @m-y: I have a related question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409154/binding-a-listkeyvaluepairstring-listdatatable-items-control-wpf
Any help will be greatly appreciated :)